# Installing dependencies in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, raspberry-pi

I am new to c and trying to learn how to write a simple makefile for my program on `raspbian`. My program has a dependency for another program `afpfs-ng`

Is this the correct syntax to make sure the dependent program is downloaded and installed?

```
all: myprogram.c
        sudo gcc -o myprogram -ansi myprogram.c
packages:
        sudo apt-get install afpfs-ng    
clean:
        ($RM) myprogram
```

Comment: You haven't declared `packages` as a prerequisite of any other target, so the only way that will run is if you do `make packages`.

Comment: For checking if dependencies are installed, you probably want to use something like automake, cmake, or similar.  Although for small projects, having a small script or `packages` make target can be much simpler.

Comment: Even if you do declare it as a prerequisite (e.g. `all: packages program.c`), you have not declared any prerequisites for `packages` itself.  So the recipe would get run *every time*.

Comment: `sudo gcc` is a bad idea. It assumes you have sudo rights at all, leaves files not owned by you in the build dir, and is plain unnecessary to run a compiler. Compilers should be run with user privileges, because they're not typically scrutinized for security.

Comment: @larsmans - Thanks - good point. I removed sudo.

Comment: installing dependencies in makefile is correct way of doing? Or should we prepare the build environment before of executing make command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the correct syntax to make sure the dependent program is downloaded and installed?

If the package name is correct, this is the correct syntax to make `make packages` work. It does assume that the person running the program has sudo rights to execute `apt-get`. It also runs that command unconditionally for `make packages`, but that shouldn't be too much of a problem because `apt-get` will check if the package is already installed.

The main problem is that `make all` doesn't execute `make packages`, which can be accomplished with

```
all: myprogram.c packages
        # command
```

Since `apt-get` is inherently non-portable, it's correct if it works on your box :)

Comment: I updated the OP to indicate raspbian, which was an over site while writing the post.